# SQL INNER JOIN on Text Columns

Tags: sql, text, inner-join

I have two tables (equipment & software) that I want to do an `INNER JOIN` on. They both have a field called EQCN. It is a text field. I get the following error:

> The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.

There has to be a way around this.

Comment: What length is the longest entry in these columns?

Comment: @Oded - Not really needed. This is the error you get if you try and join 2 columns both of which are of the `text` datatype.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Fair enough. I never tried to join on a `text` column :)

Comment: @Oded - No, does seem unusual. I suspect it probably doesn't need to be `text` / `varchar(max)`.

Comment: It makes my blood run cold to think of someone trying to join on text or varchar(max). These are datatypes that should not be used in joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the data types for these columns to `varchar(max)`.

[From Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx):

> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version
>   of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is odd, Microsoft suggests doing an indirect comparison on a text or ntext using something like SUBSTRING. Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 ON SUBSTRING(t1.textcolumn, 1, 20) = SUBSTRING(t2.textcolumn, 1, 20)
```

This of course raises a whole other set of issues like, what if the first # of characters are identical, etc. I would suggest going the route of changing the type if you can first, rather than take this advice.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Doing a join on a TEXT field would be VERY slow, even if it did work.  Perhaps use:

```
CONVERT(varchar, myColumnName) = 'my value'
```

Comment: That will truncate it to `30` characters and change the semantics.